# NUXT3 - DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '0' is not a valid attribute name

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

Please check my 2 steps :

[First click on "Add jobs"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bQOa.png)

I receive the error : DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '0' is not a valid attribute name.

[Second click to refresh the entire page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIdve.png)

Everything is ok.

So I don't understand why page isn't display on first click.

The error come with my card component. When I disable it, error disappear.

Component (card) :

```js
<template>
  <div class="select-none mb-6 w-full">
    <div class="mx-5 w-72 static">
      <button @click="clicHeart" class="relative z-10 p-1 left-60 top-12 bg-white rounded-full">
        <svg class="w-5 h-5 stroke-red-500" :class="heart ? 'fill-red-500' : 'fill-none'"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor">
          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
            d="M21 8.25c0-2.485-2.099-4.5-4.688-4.5-1.935 0-3.597 1.126-4.312 2.733-.715-1.607-2.377-2.733-4.313-2.733C5.1 3.75 3 5.765 3 8.25c0 7.22 9 12 9 12s9-4.78 9-12z" />
        </svg>
      </button>

      <div class="relative pb-64 z-0">
        <NuxtImg quality='80' sizes="xs:300px sm:500px md:700px lg:900px xl:1100px"
          class="absolute w-full h-full rounded-lg object-cover border-b shadow-md" :src="offer_image_url"
          :alt="offer_title"></NuxtImg>
      </div>

      <OfferQuestionMarkPopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicQuestionMark" class="mb-20" />
      <AddOfferCountryPopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicCountry" class="mb-20" />
      <OfferProductPopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicProduct" class="mb-20" />
      <OfferServicePopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicService" class="mb-20" />
      <OfferPlacePopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicPlace" class="mb-20" />
      <OfferFacebookPopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicFacebook" class="mb-20" />
      <OfferInstagramPopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicInstagram" class="mb-20" />
      <OfferYoutubePopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicYoutube" class="mb-20" />
      <OfferTiktokPopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicTiktok" class="mb-20" />
      <OfferBlogPostsPopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicBlogPosts" class="mb-20" />
      <OfferPhotoPopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicPhoto" class="mb-20" />
      <OfferVideoPopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicVideo" class="mb-20" />
      <OfferModelPopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicModel" class="mb-20" />
      <OfferTeacherPopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicTeacher" class="mb-20" />
      <OfferFranchisePopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicFranchise" class="mb-20" />
      <OfferHeartNumberPopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicHeartNumber" class="mb-20" />
      <OfferDetailsPopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicDetails" class="mb-20" />
      <OfferProfilePopup v-bind="offer" @close-popup="closeAllPopup" v-if="clicProfile" class="mb-20" />

      <div class="flex flex-col px-4 -mt-16 relative z-10 h-80">
        <!-- Container Card  -->
        <div class="bg-white flex flex-col justify-between rounded-lg shadow-lg border h-80 static">
          <!-- Container Title / Badges  -->
          <div class="relative">
            <!-- Container Title  -->
            <div class="flex flex-row justify-between">
              <div class="w-48">
                <div class="h-8 w-48 overflow-hidden font-bold z-40 text-lg mt-3 ml-5 hover:text-xs">
                  {{ offer_title }}
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="mb-2">
                <button @click="clicOnQuestionMark"
                  class="mt-2 bg-grey-500 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-black mr-2 mb-2">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                      d="M2.25 12c0-5.385 4.365-9.75 9.75-9.75s9.75 4.365 9.75 9.75-4.365 9.75-9.75 9.75S2.25 17.385 2.25 12zm11.378-3.917c-.89-.777-2.366-.777-3.255 0a.75.75 0 01-.988-1.129c1.454-1.272 3.776-1.272 5.23 0 1.513 1.324 1.513 3.518 0 4.842a3.75 3.75 0 01-.837.552c-.676.328-1.028.774-1.028 1.152v.75a.75.75 0 01-1.5 0v-.75c0-1.279 1.06-2.107 1.875-2.502.182-.088.351-.199.503-.331.83-.727.83-1.857 0-2.584zM12 18a.75.75 0 100-1.5.75.75 0 000 1.5z"
                      clip-rule="evenodd" />
                  </svg>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Container Badges  -->

            <div class="pl-2 pr-2 flex flex-wrap">
              <div>
                <button @click="clicOnCountry"
                  class="inline-block bg-stone-500 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-white mr-2 mb-2">#{{
                    offer.country_name }}
                </button>
              </div>
              <div v-if="offer.place">
                <button @click="clicOnPlace"
                  class="inline-block bg-pink-300 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#place</button>
              </div>
              <div v-if="offer.product">
                <button @click="clicOnProduct"
                  class="inline-block bg-teal-300 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#product
                </button>
              </div>
              <div v-if="offer.service">
                <button @click="clicOnService"
                  class="inline-block bg-amber-300 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#service
                </button>
              </div>
              <div v-if="offer.facebook">
                <button @click="clicOnFacebook"
                  class="inline-block bg-sky-300 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#facebook</button>
              </div>
              <div v-if="offer.instagram">
                <button @click="clicOnInstagram"
                  class="inline-block bg-purple-300 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#instagram</button>
              </div>
              <div v-if="offer.youtube">
                <button @click="clicOnYoutube"
                  class="inline-block bg-red-300 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#youtube</button>
              </div>
              <div v-if="offer.tiktok">
                <button @click="clicOnTiktok"
                  class="inline-block bg-gray-300 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#tiktok</button>
              </div>
              <div v-if="offer.posts">
                <button @click="clicOnBlogPosts"
                  class="inline-block bg-green-300 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#blogposts</button>
              </div>
              <div v-if="offer.photo">
                <button @click="clicOnPhoto"
                  class="inline-block bg-yellow-300 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#photo</button>
              </div>
              <div v-if="offer.video">
                <button @click="clicOnVideo"
                  class="inline-block bg-cyan-300 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#video</button>
              </div>
              <div v-if="offer.model">
                <button @click="clicOnModel"
                  class="inline-block bg-lime-300 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#model</button>
              </div>
              <div v-if="offer.teacher">
                <button @click="clicOnTeacher"
                  class="inline-block bg-pink-300 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#teacher</button>
              </div>
              <div v-if="offer.franchise">
                <button @click="clicOnFranchise"
                  class="inline-block bg-emerald-300 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#franchise</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <!-- Container Image  -->
            <div>
              <div class="flex justify-between pb-3 px-4">
                <button @click="clicOnHeartNumber"
                  class="flex flex-row bg-red-300 rounded-full px-3 text-xs font-semibold text-white mr-2 mb-2">
                  <div class="mt-1">
                    {{ offer.heart_number }}
                  </div>
                  <svg class="ml-1 mt-0.5 w-5 h-5 stroke-red-500 fill-red-500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                      d="M21 8.25c0-2.485-2.099-4.5-4.688-4.5-1.935 0-3.597 1.126-4.312 2.733-.715-1.607-2.377-2.733-4.313-2.733C5.1 3.75 3 5.765 3 8.25c0 7.22 9 12 9 12s9-4.78 9-12z" />
                  </svg>
                </button>
                <button @click="clicOnProfile">
                  <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full" :src="offer.user_image_url" :alt="offer.user_name" />
                </button>
                <button @click="clicOnDetails"
                  class="flex flex-row bg-teal-500 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-xs font-semibold text-white mr-2 mb-2">
                  Details
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>

import { ref } from 'vue'
const route = useRoute();
const supabase = useSupabaseClient();
const user = useSupabaseUser();

let heart = ref(false);
const clicQuestionMark = ref(false);
const clicCountry = ref(false);
const clicProduct = ref(false);
...

function closeAllPopup() {
  clicProduct.value = false;
  clicService.value = false;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
  clicCountry.value = false;
...
}

function clicOnQuestionMark() {
  clicCountry.value = false;
  clicQuestionMark.value = !clicQuestionMark.value
  clicProduct.value = false;
  clicService.value = false;
...

}

function clicOnCountry() {

  clicCountry.value = !clicCountry.value;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
  clicProduct.value = false;
...

}

function clicOnProduct() {

  clicProduct.value = !clicProduct.value;
  clicService.value = false;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
...
}

function clicOnService() {

  clicService.value = !clicService.value;
  clicProduct.value = false;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
...
}

function clicOnPlace() {

  clicPlace.value = !clicPlace.value;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
  clicCountry.value = false;
...
}

function clicOnFacebook() {

  clicPlace.value = false
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
  clicCountry.value = false;
  clicProduct.value = false;
...
}

function clicOnInstagram() {

  clicPlace.value = false;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
  clicCountry.value = false;
  clicProduct.value = false;
...
}

function clicOnYoutube() {
  clicPlace.value = false;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
  clicCountry.value = false;
  clicProduct.value = false;
...
}

function clicOnTiktok() {
  clicPlace.value = false;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
  clicCountry.value = false;
  clicProduct.value = false;
...
}

function clicOnBlogPosts() {
  clicPlace.value = false;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
  clicCountry.value = false;
  clicProduct.value = false;
...
}

function clicOnPhoto() {
  clicPlace.value = false;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
  clicCountry.value = false;
...
}

function clicOnVideo() {
  clicPlace.value = false;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
  clicCountry.value = false;
  clicProduct.value = false;
...
}

function clicOnModel() {
  clicPlace.value = false;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
  clicCountry.value = false;
  clicProduct.value = false;
 ...
}

function clicOnTeacher() {
  clicPlace.value = false;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
  clicCountry.value = false;
  clicProduct.value = false;
...
}

function clicOnFranchise() {
  clicPlace.value = false;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
  clicCountry.value = false;
  clicProduct.value = false;
...
}

function clicOnHeartNumber() {
  clicPlace.value = false;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
  clicCountry.value = false;
...
}

function clicOnDetails() {
  clicPlace.value = false;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
  clicCountry.value = false;
...
}

function clicOnProfile() {
  clicPlace.value = false;
  clicQuestionMark.value = false;
...
}

const offer = defineProps({
  active: Boolean,
  country_name: String,
  heart_number: Number,
  facebook: Boolean,
  franchise: Boolean,
  instagram: Boolean,
  model: Boolean,
  offer_image_url: String,
  offer_text: String,
  offer_title: String,
  photo: Boolean,
  place: Boolean,
  posts: Boolean,
  product: Boolean,
  service: Boolean,
  teacher: Boolean,
  tiktok: Boolean,
  user_name: String,
  user_phone_number: Number,
  user_image_url: String,
  video: Boolean,
  youtube: Boolean,
})


function clicHeart() {
  heart.value = !heart.value;
}

</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Comment: just share all things here.

Comment: I have no other things

Comment: You need to provide the code that is executed when you click add jobs. Its not possible to understand the issue without seeing the code.

Comment: There should be setAttribute defined somewhere.

Comment: The error message is because you are trying to set attribute with name "0", which is not possible. But we can't tell you why it is happening, when we don't see your source code.

Comment: I add component card. I need to wait 30 min to post add job page code.

Comment: I think everything is online. I just delete some useless code

Comment: My god ! Just because I create my offer object with an array...  I now use offer = {} an not : offer = [{}]

Answer (score 0):

0 was the index of the array...

I just replace :

```
let offer = [
{
    'active': _active,
    'country_name': _country_name,
    ...
}
```

]

with :

```
let offer =
{
    'active': _active,
    'country_name': _country_name,
    ...
}
```